# How to add a prefix to a groovy string?

Tags: groovy

I have a string that contains IPCM_20120223_xml.tar.gz and i want to change it to USLF_20120223_xml.tar.gz How can I change only the prefix from IPCM to USLF ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is 2 ways to do it.

```
    def inital = "IPCM_20120223_xml.tar.gz"

    def result1 = inital.replaceFirst("IPCM_", "USLF_")
    def result2 = "USLF${inital.substring(4)}"

    assert "USLF_20120223_xml.tar.gz" == result1
    assert "USLF_20120223_xml.tar.gz" == result2
```

Depending on what generates the initial name for you you may want one over the other.

First way would be good if you know it always starts with "IPCM_" and that character sequence is never anywhere but on the front.

Second way would be good if you know it always starts with a 4 letter sequence and you don't care what it is but you want to change it to USLF.

Comment: You could use `"USLF${initial.drop( 4 )}"` as well

Comment: or `"USLF${initial[4..-1]}"` if you're using Groovy < 1.8.1

Comment: Oops, I missed the `initial.substring(4)` which is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
def inital = "IPCM_20120223_xml.tar.gz"

def result3 = 'USLF'+inital-'IPCM'
assert "USLF_20120223_xml.tar.gz" == result3
```